# How to add data to a specific column in an existing excel file using VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I'm currently doing automation testing and need to write a dynamic value to an existing excel document in a specific column, this is what I have so far.  Forgive I'm a novice

```
Sub WriteTRNtoExcelDoc
  Dim fileName, sheetName
  fname = "<Path_To_The_File>"
  sheetName = "Sheet1"

  Set app = Sys.OleObject("Excel.Application")
  Set book = app.Workbooks.Open(fname)
  Set sheet = book.Sheets(sheetName)

  ' What do I do next to add a value to a specific column or cell in this
  ' spreadsheet?

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You create an Excel instance in a VBScript with

```
CreateObject("Excel.Application")
```

An already running Excel instance can be grabbed with

```
GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
```

In a worksheet you can access cells by using the [`Cells`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb148836%28v=office.12%29.aspx) property:

```
Set app = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
app.Visible = True
Set book = app.Workbooks.Open(fname)
Set sheet = book.Sheets(sheetName)

sheet.Cells(2,3).Value = "foo"
```

**Edit:** If you need to find the first empty cell in a given column, you can use something like this:

```
row = 1
Do Until IsEmpty(sheets.Cells(row, 3).Value)
  row = row + 1
Loop

sheet.Cells(row, 3).Value = RemPropValue
```

Comment: Thank you, this works very well.  However, every time the script runs and pulls in a dynamic value, it needs to add this to the next row down, so it doesn't overwrite the previous value.  So if the script runs 100 times and pulls 100 different WireRequestNumbers, I need it to add a list of 100 different values in column C down to Row 100, in the Excel Document.  Does that make sense?

Comment: I created something like this:

Comment: Dim fname, sheetName
  fname = "c:\test\Book1.xls"
  sheetName = "Sheet1"

Set app = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
app.Visible = True
Set book = app.Workbooks.Open(fname)
Set sheet = book.Sheets(sheetName)

Row = Row + 1

sheet.Cells(Row,3).Value = RemPropValue


End Sub

Comment: I don't think this will work, because your script would need to "remember" the previous value of `Row`. See my updated answer for a different approach.